# iOS EXC_BAD_ACCESS, but nothing is nil

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, exc-bad-access

I'm getting a really strange EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash in my app. The code that causes the crash is

```swift
private func isValidGridCoordinate(coord : CGPoint) -> Bool {
    return !((coord.x < 0) || (coord.x >= gridSize.width)
        || (coord.y < 0) || (coord.y >= gridSize.height))
}
```

But when I look at the memory in XCode, I see that the values in coord, self and gridSize are exactly as expected. Why would this error happen if none of my objects are nil?

EDIT: The code that calls this function at the crash is

```swift
private func caveCellFromGridCoordinate(coord : CGPoint) -> CaveCell? {
    if (isValidGridCoordinate(coord)) {
        return self.grid[Int(coord.y)][Int(coord.x)] as? CaveCell
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: Tried that in a playground and it works

Comment: Please post the crash log and the code using this API.

Comment: The crash log is WAY too long to post here, I'll try to see if I can find relevant parts to post. The crash happens at the end of a long loop which all calls this function.

Comment: @fafner use pastebin.com

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using `|` which is a bitwise OR operator. You want to use `||` -- the logical OR operator.

Comment: No, in Swift '|' is the OR-operator :)

Comment: This answer is correct and should be accepted – '|' is the *bitwise* OR, not the *logical* OR

Comment: Sorry, I just realized! I don't where I had that idea from, I was certain that the syntax was different in Swift.

Comment: OK, I changed it to use '||', but the same crash occurs

Comment: What is `self.grid`? Having lat/lon as array indexes makes me think the problem isn't with `isValidGridCoordinate`

Comment: Its a 2d array of cells, using NSMutableArray

Answer (score 0):

OK, so after putting in a bunch of println's, I found out that there was a logical error elsewhere in the code that was causing an overflow. Strange that I would get the error message I got, but anyway, it seems to work now